# Active Directory Login Report

Tags: powershell, active-directory

To make a long story short, we have some staff punctuality issues where we'd like to setup some type of report / monitor that would send supervisors login time stamps during morning hours mostly.  I don't know if this is possible through event logs or what not by scripting some type of report, however at this point I'm looking for solutions.   Any suggestions?

Comment: We've got something similar using scheduled tasks on our Domain Controllers that send emails based on specific events in the event log. You can have a scheduled task trigger 'on an event' by Log, Source and EventID (this question would probably work better on ServerFault rather than SO unless you have code that you're having issues with).

Comment: Collect the [`LastLogonTimestamp`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/) for their accounts on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LastlogonTimestamp is not synced in anything near real time. so that will not work for daily reporting.

i would collect the security logon events with the relevant [Event ID's](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624) and work from there with the reporting.

an alternative is to scavenge the [LastLogon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676823(v=vs.85).aspx) property from user objects. But that is non-replicated attribute so you would need to read that for a user from all DC's or where it exists.